# SQL join исключить результаты

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join

Есть 2 таблицы: applications (id, name), responses (id, master_id, application_id)

Мне нужно сделать выборку applications, исключив все записи c master_id = 2, и при этом нужно, чтобы выборка состояла еще и из тех записей, которых нет в таблице 2.

Я достигаю этого результата двумя запросами:

```
    select DISTINCT app.*, res.master_id 
    from applications app, responses res
        where res.application_id = app.id 
            and app.id not in
            (select responses.application_id from responses where responses.master_id = 2)
    select app.*, res.master_id 
    from applications app 
        LEFT join responses res 
            on res.application_id = app.id 
            where res.id is null
```

Вопрос заключается в том чтобы сделать эту выборку одним запросом?

Пробовал такой запрос, но выборка неверная:

```
    select DISTINCT app.*, res.master_id 
    from applications app 
        LEFT join responses res 
            on res.application_id = app.id 
            and app.id <>
            (select responses.application_id from responses where responses.master_id = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Мне нужно сделать выборку applications, исключив все записи c master_id = 2, и при этом нужно, чтобы выборка состояла еще и из тех записей, которых нет в таблице 2.

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM applications a
LEFT JOIN responses r ON a.id = r.application_id AND r.master_id = 2
WHERE r.application_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.